# AS3- Trying to flip a MovieClip horizontally, but it's children won't flip properly?

Tags: actionscript-3

There is a level one `MovieClip` that contains a player. There are a separate `MovieClip` that is contained inside the player `MovieClip` which is the "arms" for the player. The player flips horizontally, but the `MovieClip` children such as the 'arms" inside the player will not flip horizontally.

In the level one class I put:

```
if (mouseX > player.x)
{
    player.scaleX = 1;
    crosshair.x = mouseX;
}
else if (mouseX < player.x)
{
    player.scaleX = -1;
    crosshair.x = mouseX;
}
```

I added a download to my files because it's a bit hard to explain. The code is located in `PageOne.as`.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lf17oj29iuk761/Subject%20Unstable.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate not your player instance, but the innerclip only.

Try to change your code in this way, seems work properly:

```
if (mouseX > player.x)
{

    player.playerStand.scaleX = 1;
    player.turret.scaleY = 1;
    player.armBottom.scaleY = 1;
    player.armTop.scaleY = 1;
    player.armBottom.scaleX = 1;
    player.armTop.scaleX = 1;
    crosshair.x = mouseX;

}
else if (mouseX < player.x)
{

    player.playerStand.scaleX = -1;

    if(player.playerHasPrimary){

        player.turret.scaleY = -1;
        player.armBottom.scaleY = -1;
        player.armTop.scaleY = -1;                  
        player.armBottom.scaleX = 1;
        player.armTop.scaleX = 1;

    }
    else
    {

        player.armBottom.scaleY = 1;
        player.armTop.scaleY = 1;                   
        player.armBottom.scaleX = -1;
        player.armTop.scaleX = -1;

    }

    crosshair.x = mouseX;

}
```

to control the variable playerHasPrimary you have to change the scope to public. 
So in Player.as change:

```
public var playerHasPrimary: Boolean = true;
```

Comment: I tried that code, if you use that code and press the "1" key, and the arm changes frames. You can see that when the arm changes to frame 3, it starts to flip vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: i didn't read all code, what do exactly "1" button ?
Where is implementated?
I think you can easily adjust that function using the same logic

Comment: It's implemented in the player class. The 1 button changes the armTop, armBottom frames.

Comment: I also am wondering one thing, how come it's scaleY instead of scaleX?